# Cannot collect alle results of asynchronous call with geo.getLocations (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops, callback

Below is my code. The problem is that recordsOut[0] is always undefined, whatever I try.

I know it has to do with the callback result. I tried to add some delays to give it more time to give a result back, but that did not help.

Any idea (with example please)? Very much appreciated.

```
function getAddress(id, searchValue) {
    geo.getLocations(searchValue, function(result) {
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
            var recordsOutStr = id + ';' + searchValue + ';';
            for (var j = 0; j < result.Placemark.length; j++)
                recordsOutStr += result.Placemark[j].address + ';' + result.Placemark[j].Point.coordinates[0] + ';' + result.Placemark[j].Point.coordinates[1];
            recordsOut.push(recordsOutStr);
            alert(recordsOutStr);
        }
        else {
            var reason = "Code " + result.Status.code;
            if (reasons[result.Status.code])
                reason = reasons[result.Status.code]
            alert('Could not find "' + searchValue + '" ' + reason);
        }
    });   
}

function delay(ms) 
{
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do 
  { 
    curDate = new Date(); 
  }
  while (curDate - date < ms);
} 

function processData()
{
   objDataIn = document.getElementById("dataIn");
   objDataOut = document.getElementById("dataOut");

   if (objDataIn != null)
   {
       //alert(objDataIn.value);
       if (objDataOut != null) {

           recordsIn = explode(objDataIn.value, ';', true);
           //for (i = 0; i < recordsIn.length; i++)
           for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) 
           {
               addressStr = recordsIn[i]['address'] + ', ' +
                            recordsIn[i]['postalcode'] + ' ' +
                            recordsIn[i]['city'] + ', ' +
                            recordsIn[i]['country'];
               getAddress(recordsIn[i]['id'], addressStr); //This will set resultStr
               delay(200);
           }
           delay(5000);
           alert('***' + recordsOut[0] + '***');
           alert('***' + recordsOut[1] + '***');
           alert('***' + recordsOut[2] + '***');
           alert('***' + recordsOut[3] + '***');
           alert('***' + recordsOut[4] + '***');
       }
   }
   document.frmGeoCoder.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have already defined recordsOut like this:

```
var recordsOut = [];
```

If you do it like this - `var recordsOut;` - it will be undefined.

If that doesn't work for you, please post the rest of the code, so we can see exactly what's going on.